# htaccess RewriteEngine working for HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I am trying to redirect URLs such as `www.mysite.com/foo/bar` to `www.mysite.com/foo/index.php?foo=bar`.

To do this I am using a couple of lines in the `.htaccess` file, they are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^foo/([a-z]+)/?$    foo/index.php?bar=$1 [NC,L]
```

This works great for connections made over HTTP but I really need this to work over HTTPS as well. When I go to `https://www.mysite.com/foo/bar` I just get presented with the `404 Not Found` error page.

Any help to get this working over HTTPS (or an explanation as to why it cannot be done over HTTPS) would be great. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
After reading a few comments here is a bit of an update.

- I do have an SSL certificate for the site and HTTPS is working fine elsewhere on the site
- The document root is the same for both the HTTPS and the HTTP versions of the site. I checked this out using `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` - both return the same thing.
- I did notice that (when I removed my customised 404 page) that the error shown is: `The requested URL document_root/public_html/foo/index.php was not found on this server.` I do not have any idea why this might be the case when, if I access the file directly, I can use it fine.

Hopefully this extra info might help a bit.

Comment: did your site work before with https without the rewrite engine?

Comment: Yes, I have an SSL certificate and everything else works well with HTTPS. If I go on `https://www.mysite.com/foo/index.php?foo=bar` it all works as it should, just not with the rewrite.

Comment: Are you sure DOCUMENT_ROOT for HTTPS site is same as HTTP site?

Comment: Yep, using `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` I get the same thing when loading the page using HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching for solutions and looking at examples of `.htaccess` files I found the solution. I needed to add the following line to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /
```

I am still unsure as to why, without this line, it worked using HTTP but not HTTPS but everything is working well with the addition of this line.

I am no expert in this area but I found a nice explanation of what `RewriteBase` does here (Line 4): http://randomtype.ca/blog/the-wordpress-htaccess-file-explained/